# Kubernetes - Best Way to Perform Rolling Update w/ Fingerprinted Files

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

More of a conceptual question than anything else but I am trying to figure out what the best approach is to handle a rolling update to my side project without causing intermittent 404's to old files.

To clarify; while the new revision is deploying to the cluster, it is possible for one pod to request files from an old pod which has different file fingerprints, and thus ends up 404'ing. My current solution is a double-deploy with a fallback, but this seems a bit archaic for a problem which is likely faced by a lot of people using k8s.

I'm not going to provide any config files here as it shouldn't really have any impact on any solution as I'm really looking for more of a pointer towards if there exists some core feature for either deferring rollover or otherwise that would allow this to be done without a dual deployment of both the new and old version.

Comment: This will likely lead to opinions, not factual answers, but I'm not voting to close because there might be a common solution nowadays that wasn't present when I was doing a lot of devops. Putting the build-unique assets in object storage (behind a caching CDN) was my standard practice.

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with opinions, if anything just want options more so than any opinionated answer for my use case, hence why the kubectl configs were omitted. But yeah, if there's a one-size fits all solution recommended by k8s then that'd be preferable.